# JavaScript parenthesis effect on type conversions during addition

Tags: javascript, types

In JavaScript, we have `{} + [] // 0` but `({}+[]) // "[object Object]"`. 
I understand that in the first example, JS parses `{}` as an empty block, and so is left with `+ []`, at which point it calls `toNumber(toPrimitive([]))`, which is 0. But I don't understand how any of this changes by adding parenthesis. Does parenthesis stop JS from evaluating `{}` as an empty block, and instead converts it to its primitive, aka a string?

Comment: Adding parenthesis makes it evaluate as an object literal instead of a code block. This trick is used in [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](//stackoverflow.com/q/28770415)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many circumstances in JavaScript when adding parentheses changes the parsing of the following token. Function declarations vs. function expressions are another example.

This is a syntax error:

```
function() {
    // stuff
}()
```

But this is an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression):

```
(function() {
    // stuff
})()
```

In this case, the parentheses causes JavaScript to interpret the curly brackets as an **object literal** instead of an empty block. Objects get coerced to their string representation when used with the binary + operator. Arrays get coerced to the empty string when added with a string.

```
{} + {} // "[object Object][object Object]"
'foo' + [] // "foo"
({} + []) // "[object Object]"
```

The parenthesis did not cause the `{}` to become a string, but the plus sign did.

Comment: In some circumstances `{} + {}` prints `NaN` instead. It depends on whether the REPL chooses to parse the first `{}` as an object literal or not.